# perl, unix: fastest way to merge thousands of small files into one file

Tags: perl, unix

what is the fastest way to merge thousands of small files into one file?

thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `cat` command works nicely:

```
cat *someglob* > output.txt
```

It's name (short for con**cat**enate) even gives away its purpose.

If your argument list is too long (i.e. too many files are matched by the glob) you can always use the `find` command and pipe the arguments to `xargs`.

```
find . -name \*someglob\* -print0 | xargs -0 cat > output.txt
```

Comment: Nice answer, but when he come from Windows will have no idea what you mean with *someglob* ;)

Comment: @jm666: Both the question title and tags include "unix". But the truth is, a "glob" has the same meaning on Unix-like systems and Windows...It's a pattern that can be used to match a bunch of strings

Comment: @Sean, Not really "Catenation is the ability of a chemical element to form a long chain-like structure via a series of covalent bonds." "catenate" may be short for "concatenate", but "cat" isn't short for "catenate".

Comment: @ikegami: Yes really.  dictionary.reference.com says catenate means "to link together; form into a connected series."

Comment: Globbing won't work if the number of files matched exceeds a limit ...   http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/coreutils-faq.html#Argument-list-too-long

Comment: Nit: It's not the number of files that limited @Bart, it's the memory taken by the argument list.

Comment: @Bart and @ikegami: Okay, that's easily remedied with `find` and `xargs` (answer updated)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure `cat` is faster, and simpler, but here's a perl version, just because you asked about it.

```
perl -pe1 *.txt > all.txt
```

Courtesy of [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami)

Comment: You are treating the results of the glob as a glob. That's a bug. For example, it fails if you have a file named `foo bar.txt`. Fix: `perl -pe1 *.txt > all.csv`

Comment: @ikegami that gives me the error "Can't open *.txt: Invalid argument." I'm on windows, perhaps the bash shell expands perl's variables before they are passed, I could not say. On my system, variables (even globs) are passed as-is. It works fine with `foo bar.txt`.

Comment: @TLP, Kettle black? Your solution doesn't run in the cmd shell either. More importantly, it doesn't run in bash, which is surely what the OP wants.

Comment: @ikegami I don't know what you mean by "kettle black". My solution most assuredly did run in my cmd shell, even with the "foo bar.txt". If you want to complain about it, be more specific than "doesn't run". **Your** solution should run in bash, which is the one in the answer now. I'm not sure what else you could possibly want.

Comment: No @TLP, your original answer doesn't run in cmd. One gets "`> was unexpected at this time.`" because of the incorrect quoting.

Comment: @ikegami Well, yes.. since the OP used bash, I changed the quotes to single, and the `qq()` to double. The original that I tested was `perl -we "@ARGV = glob(qq(@ARGV)); print while (<>);" *.txt > all.csv"` Are you quite satisfied that everything is stated correctly now, or do you wish to point out any other mistakes I made? =P

Answer (score 0):

In case it's more helpful, here's an example of how you might do that on the command-line:

```
cd dir_with_thousand_files
cat *.txt > onebigfile.txt
```